# How to apply paging to the data I am fetching from database?

Tags: pagination, joomla2.5

I have created a module using MVC for displaying the some records from the database on a page.

Now I want to apply paging on the record so that only 5 records should display on a page. So I need help regarding pagination.

I want to apply paging of 1,2,3,4 not the next and previous links.

So Is there any module for it.

Any one who can help me?
I am using joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

for some reason pagination within any framework is always tricky...

You need to add some specific code and extend certain classes in both view and model.

1. Make sure your model extends `JModelList`
2. In the model overload `protected function getListQuery()` and return your select query with select + from + where + order... do not include limit. Must return the query from `$db->getQuery` and not the loaded results. Manipulate `list.start` and `list.limit` in the model to control start and # of results per page
3. In your view get the pagination `$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');` and items `$this->items = $this->get('Items');`
4. display your data and the pagination, to display pagination simply use `echo $this->pagination->getListFooter()`

This is it!
To learn more look [Joomla 2.5 MVC Guide](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5), [Basic Back-end section](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_07) shows how to use pagination.